# Como ABRIR um arquivo que está em um array de bytes?

Tags: c#

A situação é a seguinte: Eu tenho um banco onde guardo alguns arquivos em array de bytes(esses arquivos são E-MAILS DO OUTLOOK da extensão .msg). A finalidade disto nada mais é do que isso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu clicar ali em abrir anexo eu só quero que ele transforme o byte[] em arquivo de novo e abra o arquivo para poder encaminhar o e-mail ... esse tipo de coisa.

**Linguagem C#**